# Not appending the actual HTML in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, faye, content-tag

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.0.8. I'm trying to follow the tutorial by Ryan Bates [found here.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)

Here is all of my code, then I'll explain what it's doing:

***messages/index.html.erb***

```
<ul id="chat">
  <%= render @messages %>
</ul>

<br/>
<%= form_for Message.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

***messages/_message.html.erb*** (I'm using content tags vs. pure html)

```
<%= content_tag :li do %>
  <%= content_tag :span, :class => "created_at" do %>
    <%= message.created_at.strftime("%H:%M") %>
  <% end %>
  <%= message.content %>
<% end %>
```

*** messages/create.js.erb ***

```
<% broadcast "/messages/new" do %>
  $("#chat").append("<%= escape_javascript render(@message) %>");
<% end %>

$("#new_message")[0].reset();
```

I think that's all of the relevant code. My problem is that when I click 'Send', it's adding the pure html to my 'chat'. But if I refresh the page, that html is no longer there until I submit a new message.

*** Before Refresh ***

[image]

Just from looking at this, it looks like the html is completely incorrect, the ending tag for span and li aren't right. Why would this be happening? But when I refresh, it looks pretty much fine.

*** After Refresh ***

[image]

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`escape_javascript` broke in Rails 3.0.8 -- upgrade to Rails 3.0.9 (which came out today) to resolve the issue.

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/6/16/ann-rails-3-0-9-has-been-released

(The SafeBuffer issues mentioned in the release announcement's "Changes" section has to do with `escape_javascript`)

Comment: It will let me accept your answer in 5 minutes. Thank you for being very quick and accurate.